# Nautilus - How do I set the default window size?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nautilus

I wish to slightly enlarge the default size of Nautilus windows. What I tried so far:

1. Change the window size manually hoping it is remembered. It is, but only until I reboot.
2. Change the `org.gnome.nautilus.window-state.initial-size` entry in dconf-editor. Same result.

Is there a way to set the default size or is it hard-coded somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I've found dconf-editor somewhat unreliable, at least since updating to 19.04. gsettings gets the job done from the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state initial-size '(X,Y)'
```

(Replace X and Y with your desired values.)

This change persists through reboot on my machine.